# Configuring traefik using labels in docker not working?

Tags: docker-compose, traefik, consul

I am using *traefik* with consul as backend, and I need to configure my services with *traefik* dynamically, In the docs they do that using the `labels` config parameter something like:

```
  whoami:
    image: containous/whoami # A container that exposes an API to show its IP address
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:whoami.docker.localhost"
```

But this did not work for me, instead of that it worked using the `environment` config parameter as follow:

```
version: "3.7"
services:

  consul:
    image: consul
    command: consul agent -server -dev -client=0.0.0.0 -ui -bootstrap -log-level warn
    ports:
      - "8400:8400"
      - "8500:8500"
      - "8600:53/udp"

  registrator:
    image: gliderlabs/registrator:latest
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock
    depends_on:
      - consul
    command: -internal consul://consul:8500

  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik
    command: --api --consulcatalog.endpoint=consul:8500
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml
    depends_on:
      - registrator  

  inventory:
    build:docker container in 
      context: ./inventory
    expose:
      - "5000"
    environment:
      - SERVICE_TAGS=traefik.enable=true,traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http,traefik.frontend.rule=Host:inventory.docker.localhost
```

When using labels traefik does not detect the configuration, Any idea why this happening?

**Note:** If you need any other details please write a comment.

Comment: don't you need the volume declaration `/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` in your `reverse-proxy` service as well?